# Magento 2 - What's the purpose of Formkey Validator?

Tags: magento2, form-key

I want to know what does the formkey validator do : `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply  and in order :

1. `Magento/Framework/Data/Form/FormKey::getFormKey()` : generate a formkey.
2. `Magento/Framework/Data/Form/FormKey/Validator::validate()` validate that formkey.

**Exemple :** `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account::LoginPost.php`

```
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        ...
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

Here magento check : if a user is already logged in `$this->session->isLoggedIn()` or a formkey request is not valide `!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())`, it returns and redirects to the previous page.